# cant link to CSS in HTML in localhost

Tags: html, css, localhost

I can't linked to my CSS file in my HTML file in localhost.
I have my index.html and styles.css in /var/www/html/project
I call it in the browser with localhost/project/index.html and only the html is printing.
When I just open the html in the browser, it's working fine.

I tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://var/www/html/project/styles.css" media="all">
```

I also tried in the href

```
localhost/project/styles.css
```

or `project/styles.css`
or `/project/styles.css`

But nothing, what am I doing wrong ?

Thx

Comment: You said "I have my index.html and **styles.html** "  You meant you have a styles.css file, right?

Comment: yes styles.css right

Comment: try using the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you put for your CSS file should be RELATIVE TO the location of your html file.

If your HTML file has the path **/var/www/html/project/index.html**, then it's location is the **project** folder.  That folder becomes the "root" of your project, and the CSS path should be relative to it:

**styles.css**

Comment: ok thx but if have my index.html in project/index.html and project/css/styles.css.
href="css/styles.css" should work ?

Comment: Are you using a local server, or are you merely opening the HTML file directly?

Comment: i'm not sure if that will answer your question but i am manually writing localhost/projet/index.html in mozilla or chrome

Comment: It seems you are serving the files to localhost.  You would need to configure your local server to handle serving the **css/styles.css** file.  You should figure out which server you are using and then do research about that server setup yourself.

Comment: If you want to view your HTML file directly, put **file:///var/www/html/project/index.html** as your URL instead.

Comment: No problem.  Remember to accept my answer as correct by clicking the check-mark to the left of my answer.  You can also upvote my answer by clicking the up arrow, if you found it particularly useful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
```

If your css file and your html file is in the same folder, you just need to reference it by name and the file extension, I think.

Comment: thx that's working but if I put my css files in a css folder the href="css/styles.css" does not work

Comment: Where is your css folder? Is it in the same folder as your html file or is it in a different location. As another commenter pointed out your href attribute value is a relative address, so what you give as a value depends on the location of css folder with reference to your html file

Comment: No problem :) Glad to help. I think the address that you have up there will work if the folder css is in created in the same folder as your html file. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If the CSS file is in the project file (with the index.html file) your link should look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: It worked like this (just the image dont appear) but if I put my css files in a css folder the href="css/styles.css" dont work...

Comment: Try this:   href="/css/styles.css"

Comment: Great!  Glad we could help.  If  you could up vote my answer or mark as correct that would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As an example for VS13 link the css as shown below:

```
  <link href="~/MyFolder/Style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found a solution. You don't need anything. Do

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
    /* Your code */
</style>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
    // Your code
</script>
```

Don't link them. Do it Internal. Thanks me later

Answer (score -1):

So I added type = text/css and thx the CSS is working, but if I move my CSS in a CSS folder css/styles.css is not working
with my html file in /var/www/html/project/index.html
and my css file in /var/www/html/project/css/styles.css

But in any case images are not charging :

and I have my images in /var/www/html/project/img/banner.jpg